# Google App Engine Vs. Google Apps Script (Within Business Apps)

Tags: google-app-engine, http, google-apps-script

I've been thinking of creating an online service that heavily depends on HTTP GET/POST requests and some backend processing. But I'm a little confused on which is the best choice of these: Google App Engine or Google Apps Script?

I know Google App Script deals mainly with the other Google products, but that I don't mind; I can write scripts to handle my requests, do the processing, and make databases out of spreadsheets. Yes it's somewhat tiresome, but Google Business Apps is quite attractive to me since I already use it.

I haven't used a PaaS before to be honest. How would App Engine be any better? technically, pricing-wise, business-wise, security-wise... etc.

Comment: I don't know App Engine pricing, but surely the **greatest** difference between them will be quotas. On Apps Script you have to deal with various quotas, from execution time limit, data sizes, amount of API calls per minute, per day, etc. On App Engine there's no such tight limits, and if you pay more you'll get more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depend on what you want to do.

If you except a heavy load, AppEngine is scalable and permit to handle many requests per second. It launch more instances automatically.
AppEngine have some free quotas and if you develop your application correctly by using memcache you can stay under these quotas.

Doing service with App Engine is completely different than Apps Script which is juste kind of javascript. You can use Python, Java, PHP or Go on App Engine. And if you want to communicate with other Google's products you need to authenticate which is a little bit more complicated than App Script.

Comment: Seems like App Engine is the goto solution on technical and cost perspectives. But what else am I getting from App Engine? I'm also having difficulty understanding the pricing.

Comment: 100% in appengine. Apps script is not for this mainly because of quotas and stability (apps script comes without any SLA)

Comment: The SLA is a very good point!